# CognitoIdentityCredentials expired

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Have got the IdentityPool created and userPool too.

Region, AccountId, IdentityPoolId and roleArn passed as params do hold the correct values.

A call to CognitoIdentityCredentials

```
AWS.config.region = region;

AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
  AccountId: accountId,
  IdentityPoolId: identityPoolId,
  RoleArn: roleArn,
});
```

returns (sensitive credentials obfuscated)

```
{
    "expired": true,
    "expireTime": null,
    "refreshCallbacks": [],
    "params": {
        "AccountId": "9999999999",
        "IdentityPoolId": "eu-west-2:bcfbd1c9-1234-1234-1234-423be5c3f7d8",
        "RoleArn": "arn:aws:iam: : 999999999:role/Cognito_ElasticSearchIdentityPoolAuth_Role"
    },
    "data": null,
    "_identityId": null,
    "_clientConfig": {}
}
```

I would expect this call to return `accessKeyId` and `sessionToken`.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html

Answer (score 1):

Copied from the [CognitoIdentityCredentials](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityCredentials.html) API documentation:

> If a `RoleArn` is provided, then this provider gets credentials using the [AWS.STS.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/STS.html#assumeRoleWithWebIdentity-property) service operation, after first getting an Open ID token from [AWS.CognitoIdentity.getOpenIdToken()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html#getOpenIdToken-property).

Consequently, I suggest that you try something along the lines, starting with [CognitoIdentity.getId()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentity.html#getId-property):

```
const getIdParams = {
  IdentityPoolId: // ...
  AccountId: // ...
  Logins: {
    '<IdentityProviderName>': 'STRING_VALUE',
    /* '<IdentityProviderName>': ... */
  }
};
const {IdentityId} = await cognitoidentity.getId(getIdParams).promise();

const openIdTokenParams = {
  IdentityId,
  Logins: {
    '<IdentityProviderName>': 'STRING_VALUE',
    /* '<IdentityProviderName>': ... */
  }
};
const {Token} = await cognitoidentity.getOpenIdToken(openIdTokenParams).promise();

const assumeWebIdentityParams = {
  DurationSeconds: // ...
  ProviderId: // ...
  RoleArn: // ...
  RoleSessionName: // ...
  WebIdentityToken: Token
}
const {Credentials} = await sts.assumeRoleWithWebIdentity(assumeWebIdentityParams).promise();

console.log(Credentials);
// prints AccessKeyId, Expiration, SecretAccessKey and SessionToken
```